# How to register parent after student registration hook on 'add new user' form in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, laravel

I want to create user registration with extra field and parent registration on same page in default Add New User Form...There i use hook to insert user extra field it works fine but parent cannot be registered at time user hook works fine but parent cannot .Please help how we can add user and parent at the same time because i to make two logins one is for user and another is for parent in wordpress.

I aslo upload screenshot
Here is my code:

```
function custom_user_profile_fields($user){

     ?>
     <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
     <table class="form-table">
         <tr>
             <th><label for="user_course"><?php _e("Course");
?></label></th>
             <td>
                 <select name="user_course" id="user_course"
style="width:180px">
                     <option value="">-Select Course-</option>
                     <option value="MCA"   <?php selected( $user_course,
"MCA"); ?>>MCA</option>
                     <option value="BCA" <?php selected( $user_course,
"BCA"); ?>>BCA</option>
                 </select>
             </td>
         </tr>

             <tr>
                 <th><label for="user_gender"><?php _e("Gender");
?></label></th>
                 <td>
                     <input type="radio" name="user_gender"
id="user_gender"  <?php  checked( $gender, 'Male' ); ?> value="Male"
/>Male</label>
                     <input type="radio" name="user_gender"
id="user_gender"  <?php  checked( $gender, 'Female' ); ?> value="Female"
/>Female
                 </td>
             </tr>

             <tr>
                 <th><label for="dropdown">Roll Number</label></th>

                 <td>
                     <input type="text" class="regular-text"
name="student_roll" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta(
'student_roll', $user->ID ) ); ?>" id="student_roll" /><br />
                 </td>
             </tr>

             <tr>
                 <th><label for="dropdown">Section</label></th>
                 <td>
                     <input type="text" class="regular-text"
name="student_section" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta(
'student_section', $user->ID ) ); ?>" id="student_section" /><br />
                 </td>
             </tr>

              <input type="hidden" name="role" id="role" value="<?php
echo esc_attr('students'); ?>" />
             <tr>

                 <th><label for="dropdown">DOB</label></th>
                 <td>
                     <input type="date" class="regular-text datepicker"
name="student_dob" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" value="<?php echo
esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'student_dob', $user->ID ) ); ?>"
id="student_dob" /><br />
                 </td>

             </tr>

              <tr>

                 <th><label for="user_address"><?php _e("Address");
?></label></th>
                 <td>

                     <input type="text" class="regular-text"
name="student_address" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta(
'student_address', $user->ID ) ); ?>" id="student_address" /><br />
                 </td>

             </tr>

             <tr>

                 <th><label for="user_phone_number"><?php _e("Phone
Number"); ?></label></th>
                 <td>

                     <input type="text" class="regular-text"
name="student_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta(
'student_phone', $user->ID ) ); ?>" id="student_phone" /><br />
                 </td>

             </tr>


             <tr>

                 <th><label for="user_city"><?php _e("City");
?></label></th>
                 <td>

                     <input type="text" class="regular-text"
name="student_city" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta(
'student_city', $user->ID ) ); ?>" id="student_city" /><br />
                 </td>

             </tr>

             <tr>

                 <th><label for="user_state"><?php _e("State");
?></label></th>
                 <td>

                     <input type="text" class="regular-text"
name="student_state" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta(
'student_state', $user->ID ) ); ?>" id="student_state" /><br />
                 </td>

             </tr>

             <tr>

                 <th><label for="student_zipcode"><?php _e("Zip Code");
?></label></th>
                 <td>

                     <input type="text" class="regular-text"
name="student_zipcode" value="" id="student_zipcode" /><br />
                 </td>

             </tr>

             <tr>
              <th><h3>Parent's Detail Form</h3></th>

             </tr>
                 <input type="hidden" name="role" id="role" value="<?php
echo esc_attr('parents'); ?>" />
             <tr>
                 <th><label for="dropdown">Mother's Name</label></th>

                 <td>
                     <input type="text" class="regular-text"
name="mother_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta(
'mother_name', $user->ID ) ); ?>" id="mother_name" /><br />
                 </td>

             </tr>



         </table>
<?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( "user_new_form", "custom_user_profile_fields" );


function save_custom_user_profile_fields($user_id){
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_course', $_POST['user_course'] );
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_gender', $_POST['user_gender'] );
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'student_roll',
$_POST['student_roll'] );
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'student_section',
$_POST['student_section'] );
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'student_dob', $_POST['student_dob'] );
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'student_address',
$_POST['student_address'] );
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'student_phone',
$_POST['student_phone'] );
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'student_city',
$_POST['student_city'] );
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'student_state',
$_POST['student_state'] );
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'student_state',
$_POST['student_zipcode'] );

          add_action( 'show_user_profile',
'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
          add_action( 'edit_user_profile',
'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );

         add_action( 'personal_options_update',
'fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
          add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update',
'fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
}
add_action('user_register', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('profile_update', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');

// Parent Hook Details

// next hook
 function fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {


     update_user_meta( $user_id, 'mother_name', $_POST['mother_name'] );
 }


?>
```